# junit failure don't print in linux

Tags: linux, junit

I want to print failure string on console. I am using following code.

```
 import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
 import org.junit.runner.Result;
 import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class MyTestRunner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(MyClassTest.class);
for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
  System.out.println(failure.toString());
}
}
}
```

I get correct failure string when I execute above code in eclipse but when I tried to execute in Linux I got following

```
testSet1(PlatformPrinter): org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace please?

Comment: This is full output. There is no any error in the code, but actual string won't print.

Comment: Could you please add System.out.println(failure.getTrace()) and show the full stacktrace.